# Ionic App Availability plugin getting Error Object (...) is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am trying to implement App Availability Feature in ionic.
I have an app installed in my device and trying to check if that app exists from another app.
But facing an issue in the same, getting the below error

[image]

Comment: please share code snippet to understand your problem better way

Answer (score 3):

Possibly you are facing mismatch of ionic version of app and the plugin version you installed in your app. 
In Ionic V3 you no need to import from **'../ngx';**

**Ionic V3 and V4 have Different plugin url**

[Ionic v3  plugins](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/)

[Ionic v4 plugins](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/).

For Ionic v3 App availability

```
 ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-appavailability
 npm install --save @ionic-native/app-availability@4
```

And for Ionic V4 App availability

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-appavailability
npm install @ionic-native/app-availability
```

**npm install cmd is different for both version**

Try this steps

1. remove plugin
2. Add plugin for ionic V3 compatible from [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/app-availability/)
3. Try to build now

Comment: Hi @Sahil, Thanks for the reply. My Ionic version is v3, but still i am facing this issue. this was working in my earlier app but now its not working in the new app that i have created

Comment: @SajeedShaikh : Have you tried ionic v3 plugin because today only  i tried with my project i was facing same issue with another plugin. are you importing from .../ngx

Comment: I am importing the same from ngx and i am using the ionic v3 plugin. https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-availability. this is from where i have tried the code.

Comment: @SajeedShaikh yes bro this is only problem , in ionic v3 you dont have to import from ngx. this is v4 plugin. you have to use plugin from this [V3 plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/app-availability/)

Comment: Thanks bro, you saved my day, was struggling for this issue since yesterday. Thanks again. Really helped a lot.

Comment: @SajeedShaikh: if Problem solved then mark it answer to help others

Answer (score 0):

I had this error: with the Ionic 5/ Capacitor app.

> core.js:6479 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object String]
> at resolvePromise (zone.js:1255)
> at zone.js:1162
> at rejected (tslib.es6.js:74)
> at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:400)
> at Object.onInvoke (core.js:28705)
> at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:399)
> at Zone.run (zone.js:160)
> at zone.js:1318
> at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:434)
> at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28692) defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:6479

I have used this code and works fine now. The problem for me was I didn't have Instagram App installed on my device. So it throws an exception. I have handled it like so:

```
async goToInstagram(): Promise<void> {
    let app: string;

    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      app = 'instagram://';
    } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      app = 'com.instagram.android';
    }

    try {
      const isAppAvailable = await this.appAvailability.check(app);

      isAppAvailable
        ? this.inAppBrowser.create(`instagram://user?username=${this.item.instagram}`, '_system')
        : this.inAppBrowser.create(`https://www.instagram.com/${this.item.instagram}`, '_system');
    } catch (err) {
      this.inAppBrowser.create(`https://www.instagram.com/${this.item.instagram}`, '_system');
    }
  }
```