# ionic local notification error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: ionic-framework, notifications, ionic3, localnotification

I want to add local notification in my ionic project.I added in app.module.ts;

import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications/ngx';

and I added LocalNotifications in providers.

also in home.ts I write this codes;

```
sendLocalNotifications() {

this.localNotifications.schedule({
  title: 'Local ILocalNotification Example',
  text: 'Delayed ILocalNotification',
  trigger: {at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600)},
  led: 'FF0000',
  data: {secret: "asaddad"},

  sound: null
});
```

I also did the definition of import and constructor in home.ts.I get the following error when I run my code on android device;

```
**Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at LocalNotifications.schedule (vendor.js:92805)
    at HomePage.webpackJsonp.328.HomePage.sendLocalNotifications (main.js:2891)
    at main.js:2881
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js:5134)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:5125)
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:5125)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at o (polyfills.js:3)**
```

Can you help me?

Comment: You are facing ionic and plugin version mismatch. I described it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55139399/app-availability-feature-not-working-in-ionic/55143206#55143206

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using ionic 3 visit this link

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/local-notifications/

install cordova plugin & npm

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-local-notification
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/local-notifications@4
```

need to import in app.module.ts file

```
import {LocalNotifications} from '@ionic-native/local-notifications';
```

Add LocalNotifications in providers array [app.module.ts file]

```
 providers: [
            StatusBar,
            SplashScreen,
            ImagePicker,
            InAppBrowser,
            LoginService,
            ConnectivityService,
            Network,
            GooglePlus,
            GoogleServiceProvider,
            GoogleMapsKeyProvider,
            AppVersion,
            BarcodeScanner,
            Device,
            FCM,
            CheckStorageProvider,
            Facebook,
            Geolocation,
            TwitterConnect,
            LinkedIn,
            File,
            Camera,
            FileTransfer,
            FilePath,
            Base64,
            {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
            LocalNotifications
        ]


this.localNotifications.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
            this.localNotifications.schedule({
                id: 0,
                text: 'Delayed ILocalNotification',
                trigger: {at: date},
                foreground: true,
                vibrate: true,
                led: {color: '#FF00FF', on: 500, off: 500},
                data: {mydata: 'My hidden message this is'},
                sound: this.setSound(),
            });
        });
```

set sound by placing .mp3 sound file at src/assets/sounds/sound.mp3

```
setSound() {
        if (this.platform.is('android')) {
            return 'file://assets/sounds/sound.mp3'
        } else {
            return 'file://assets/sounds/sound.mp3'
        }
    }
```

you can read the hidden message after notification received with subscribe method 
(can add in home page or app.component.ts file)

```
if (_platform.is('cordova')) {
            this.localNotifications.on('click').subscribe((datas: any) => {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(datas));
                });
        }
```

Comment: it says;  @ionic-native/local-notifications@3.2.2
removed 1 package, updated 1 package and audited 5654 packages in 9.266s
found 2 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details